# Order by activity date of followed users

Tags: laravel

I have a "Following" feature and a polymorphic "Activity" table.

I'm trying to order the "following" "activity" by date of the activity.

How do I achieve this? For example when a thread is liked, a thread is published, a thread is published. I'd like to make it so that it shows the latest activity, but the names are locked in together and I can't separate them according to purely the activity point.

Here's some code.

Follow.php

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'following_id');
    }
```

FollowingController.php

```
$followings = Following::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
```

Blade.php

```
@foreach($followings->sortBy('created_at') as $following)

                        @foreach($following->user->activity->sortBy('created_at') as $activity)

                        @if($activity->activity_type == 'App\Thread')
                        <li class="activity">
                            <div class="activity-user">
                                <p class="avatar" style="background-color: {{ $activity->user->color }}">
                                    {{ substr($activity->user->name, 0, 1) }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="activity-body">
                                <h4><a
                                        href="/profiles/{{ $activity->user->name }}?profile-posts">{{ $activity->user->name }}</a>
                                    published <a
                                        href="/forums/{{ $activity->activity->channel->slug }}/{{ $activity->activity->slug }}/">
                                        {{ $activity->activity->title }}</a></h4>
                                <p>
                                    {!! BBCode::parse($activity->activity->body) !!}
                                </p>
                                <p class="created-at">
                                    {{-- {{ $activity->activity->created_at->format('l') }}
                                    at
                                    {{ $activity->activity->created_at->format('h:i A') }} --}}
                                    {{ $activity->activity->created_at->format('M j, Y') }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        @endif
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Can anyone show me how to sort by the date of the "activity" through the "following" relationship?

For example, 3 should be before 2 because it was created later.

[image]

Here is the table structures:

```
    Schema::create('followings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('follower_id');
        $table->dateTime('followed_date')->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('unfollowed_date')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unique(['user_id', 'follower_id']);
    });

    Schema::create('activities', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->index();
        $table->integer('activity_id')->index();
        $table->string('activity_type', 50);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->index(['activity_id', 'activity_type']);
    });
```

It looks like it works, it's just separated by name!! So I guess my question is how to I make it inclusive of all the names.

Comment: When you use sortBy it's automatically assume you want it and ASC order if you don't specify the ordering. Use sortBy('columm', 'DESC')

Comment: If is possible then share table structure so easy to understand

Comment: Hello, I have just posted it